# What are the advantages of CouchDB's validate_doc_update over a pre-DB validation server?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I am building a tiny service with API in front of a CouchDB database.

For the API, I needed to build a script verifying and pre-filtering user requests to achieve doc-specific read permissions.

I am still using CouchDB's user management for user accounts, but every request goes through an nodejs/express server that then builds the requests to the DBs.

Now I am wondering whether I should

1. use the design_docs and [validate_doc_update functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.2/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) of CouchDBs own query server to filter document updates

**or**

2. I can manage document updates within my express-server by checking the _security doc from there.

I suppose because the query-server talks directly to CouchDB through stdio validate_doc_update has performance advantages? How great are they over making a get-request to a CouchDB _security doc and the following with an insert request to CouchDB?

Are there any other advantages of one approach over the other?